# Get path as paramether on Plone view

Tags: python, python-requests, plone, plone-5.x

Here is my problem.

I'm building a view at plone 5.2, that will serve as a callback service for a outside authentication service. The problem is that the autentication service does NOT callbacks to urls with query params, so, i gotta recieve a ID that I usually recieve as query param, as part of the atual url

Ex.:

Fom this:
`domain/project/view?id=123`

to this:
`domain/project/view/123`

I know i can get the query params with `request.form` dictionary, but how can i make it so, when i call ../view/1234 it actually understands that I'm calling `view` with `id` 1234 ?

Tried using request.path, but the site understands i'm trying to access a page '1234' inside folder 'view'.

@edit:
https://training.plone.org/5/advanced-python/routing.html

I found this, but still, there is no property 'myapp.url_args', nor my page actually runs the `__call__` method when calling it with `/123` in the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to implement a method called publishTraverse. I think this page should fit your needs perfectly: https://bluedynamics.com/blog/jens/plone-traverse_subpath-for-browserviews-view-some-more-path

Comment: Thank you very much, i would spend my whole week searching and would never find that.